# React Axios API call with array loop giving wrong order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I was learning react and doing some axios api call with an array. I did a code on gathering data through coinmarketcap api to learn.

So, my intention was to get the prices from the api with a hardcoded array of cryptocurrency ids and push them into an array of prices. But I ran into a problem with the prices array, as the prices were all jumbled up. I was supposed to get an array in this order

[bitcoinprice, ethereumprice, stellarprice, rippleprice]

but when I ran it in the browser, the prices came randomly and not in this order, sometimes I got my order, sometimes it didn't. I used a button which onClick called the getPrice method. Does anyone know what went wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        cryptos:["bitcoin","ethereum","stellar","ripple"],
        prices:[]
    };

    this.getPrice = this.getPrice.bind(this);

}


getPrice(){
    const cryptos = this.state.cryptos;
    console.log(cryptos);

    for (var i = 0; i < cryptos.length; i++){       
        const cryptoUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' + cryptos[i];

    axios.get(cryptoUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            const data = response.data[0];
            console.log(data.price_usd);

            this.state.prices.push(data.price_usd);
            console.log(this.state.prices);
        })

        .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: `Axios` calls are asynchronous so the code you have written doesn't assure you will get them completed in the order you make them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to receive the data in the order of the asynchronous calls you make, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), that waits until all the promises of an array get executed and are resolved, returning the values in the order they were executed.

```
const cryptos = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'stellar', 'ripple'];
const arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cryptos.length; i++){       
    const cryptoUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' + cryptos[i];
    arr.push(axios.get(cryptoUrl));
}

Promise.all(arr).then((response) =>
  response.map(res => console.log(res.data[0].name, res.data[0].price_usd))
).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure in the for loop to capture the value of i and use it as the index once the data is returned rather than using push:

```
getPrice(){
    const cryptos = this.state.cryptos;
    console.log(cryptos);

    for (var i = 0; i < cryptos.length; i++) {
        const cryptoUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' + cryptos[i];
        (function (x) {
            axios.get(cryptoUrl)
                .then((response) => {
                    const data = response.data[0];
                    console.log(data.price_usd);

                    var newPrices = this.state.prices;
                    newPrices[x] = data.price_usd;
                    this.setState({prices: newPrices}); 
                    console.log(this.state.prices);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        })(i);
    }
}
```